# Crash inside UIKitCore. UILabel drawTextInRect

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, lldb

I have an App where I transferred a Complex UIViewController Xib and supporting code from a completely functioning App. The structure of the new VC is:

```
VC.view (defined in Interface Builder)
  subView[0] StackView
  subView[1] StackView
  subview[2] UIView
```

based on an argument passed to the VC in prepareForSegue, the subView[2] UIView contains any of three programmatically defined collectionViews.  On testing all of these subviews get defined properly. After initializing, they display properly with Xcode Quicklook.

A crash occurs after viewWillAppear(), and in-between viewIsAppearing() and viewDidAppear.  The stack trace, below appears to indicate something wrong in a [UILabel drawTextInRect]:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull set]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff86002efd0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff80048d28d __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007ff800057894 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8004a23a3 +[NSObject(NSObject) instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:] + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff800491a20 ___forwarding___ + 1459
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff800493c28 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIFoundation                        0x00007ff804ad8ff1 -[NSCoreTypesetter _NSFastDrawString:length:attributes:paragraphStyle:typesetterBehavior:lineBreakMode:rect:padding:graphicsContext:baselineRendering:usesFontLeading:usesScreenFont:scrollable:syn  6   UIFoundation                        0x00007ff804adb9b2 -[NSCoreTypesetter _stringDrawingCoreTextEngineWithOriginalString:rect:padding:graphicsContext:forceClipping:attributes:stringDrawingOptions:drawingContext:stringDrawingInterface:] + 1478
    7   UIFoundation                        0x00007ff804ad2ece __NSStringDrawingEngine + 2125
    8   UIFoundation                        0x00007ff804ad06e9 _NSStringDrawingCore + 173
    9   UIFoundation                        0x00007ff804ad4017 -[NSAttributedString(NSExtendedStringDrawing) drawWithRect:options:context:] + 91
    10  UIKitCore                           0x00000001147d5b6e -[UILabel _drawTextInRect:baselineCalculationOnly:returningDeviceMetricsOfFirstLine:forceMultiline:] + 5410
    11  UIKitCore                           0x00000001147d6d80 -[UILabel _drawTextInRect:forceMultiline:] + 41
    12  UIKitCore                           0x00000001147d6d4d -[UILabel _drawTextInRect:] + 43
    13  UIKitCore                           0x00000001147d41e2 -[UILabel drawTextInRect:] + 612
    14  UIKitCore                           0x00000001147d6e2c -[UILabel drawRect:] + 103
    15  UIKitCore                           0x00000001148a8206 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] + 610
    16  QuartzCore                          0x00007ff808e27725 CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 243
    17  QuartzCore                          0x00007ff808ff3c1d ___ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev_block_invoke + 53
    18  QuartzCore                          0x00007ff808fe9f23 -[CALayer _display] + 2167
    19  QuartzCore                          0x00007ff808ffda58 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 472
    20  QuartzCore                          0x00007ff808eff2f4 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionEdPd + 706
    21  QuartzCore                          0x00007ff808f3984a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 728
    22  QuartzCore                          0x00007ff808f3ad3a _ZN2CA11Transaction25flush_as_runloop_observerEb + 60
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8003e8d94 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8003e372a __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 534
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8003e3c72 __CFRunLoopRun + 1158
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8003e3409 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 557
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x00007ff80a648187 GSEventRunModal + 137
    28  UIKitCore                           0x00000001141dc672 -[UIApplication _run] + 972
    29  UIKitCore                           0x00000001141e10e0 UIApplicationMain + 123
```

So I put Symbolic Breakpoints on UILabel.setText and UILabel.drawTextInRect
All the setTexts appear fine, and the printouts of $arg1 on the drawTextInRect show the last pass through with filling a segmented control label (which is in subView[1].
Here is a partial listing of the arg1's:

```
<UILabel: 0x117a68220; frame = (62 15; 20 20.3333); text = 'B'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; backgroundColor = UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 0 0; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x600002673ba0>>
<UILabel: 0x117a67c90; frame = (10 8; 53 34); text = 'A'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; backgroundColor = UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 0 0; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x6000026732a0>>
<UISegmentLabel: 0x117a61690; frame = (24.3333 9.33333; 36.3333 15.6667); text = 'TextABC'; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x600002670c00>>
```

The crash occurs one instruction step after the end of viewIsAppearing.
Is there a way to determine what method "instance 0x7ff86002efd0" is?
The segue is a standard:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToSelectGlyphVC", sender: nil)
```

The prepareForSegue correctly finds the new VC and loads some Strings vars into it.

From here, how can I further trace down what the issue is with the system trying to call NSNull with a bad selector?  All of the outlets defined in the Xib appear to be properly connected to the swift code files.
Thanks!

Comment: Why did you post a new question instead of updating your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76947253/crash-on-pushviewcontroller-with-nsnull-set-unrecognized-selector)?

Comment: `set` is a method of `UIColor`. The fact that `set` is being called on `NSNull` could indicate that some color is missing that shouldn't be. If this is coming from a segmented control then perhaps it would help to delete the control from the storyboard and add a new one in its place. Make sure color are set correctly. You also mention `viewIsAppearing`. So you must be using Xcode 15 beta. Are you on the latest version of Xcode 15 beta and iOS 17 beta? Beta 7 just came out for both.

Comment: Yes, using beta7.  Interesting thought about UIColor. The last event in the stack trace was draw an attributed string. I think set is used in a number of places, but I will try setting all colors with system colors and if that doesn't work, I try deleting and reinstalling the segmented control.  Will follow up.

Comment: Commenting out the following line did the trick!  Many thanks!                       //        modeSelector.setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor(named: "mySelectorColor") as Any], for: .normal)                     even though "mySelectorColor" was appropriately defined in my Assets!

Comment: HangarRash is why I build a 50 x 60 with a nice Schweiss vertical lift door for my homebuilt!   As for the new question: the old question reflected my incomplete tracing of the crash location. It was not in the transition to the new VC, it was, as you correctly pointed out apparently a color issue (despite all parameters being defined properly) and  Xcode giving a kind of misleading message (as usual).

Comment: You should delete the old question. No need for two on the same issue. The error makes sense given the code though it's not obvious. if `UIColor(named: "mySelectorColor")` is returning a nil object then the text attributes ends up with an `NSNull` instance and when the attributed string tries to draw the colored text, it assumes it will find a `UIColor`. It tries to call `set` on the color. But since it's an `NSNull` you get the crash with the unrecognized selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack trace indicates that an attributed string is being drawn at the time of the crash. The error is about trying to call the `set` method on an instance of `NSNull`. The `set` method comes from `UIColor`. The fact that there is an `NSNull` instance instead of a `UIColor` instance suggests that some color-related attribute of the attributed string is somehow `nil` instead of a valid `UIColor` instance.

So the solution is to find where in your storyboard or where in some code you are inadvertently setting an invalid color on an attributed string. Once you fix the color reference, the crash should be resolved.